# Extracting specific fields from python object

Tags: python

This is a sample python object that I am working with.

```
class DataObj(object):

   def __init__(self, cvid, cvname, address, get_info):
      self.cvid = cvid
      self.cvname = cvname
      self.address = address
      self.prof = PROF("Honda", "Jason Jones")


class PROF(object):

    def __init__(self, organization, manager_name):
        self.organization = organization
        self.manager_name = manager_name
        self.project_list = [Proj("asd", "asd"), Proj("asdsd", "asdsd")]
class Proj(object):
     def __init__(self, projectname, projecttype):
         self.projectname = projectname
         self.projecttype = projecttype
```

I need to write a function that takes a list of fields and extract all the fields as key value pair from the **DataObj**. The trick is it should also look for attributes of object composed inside **DataObj** class.  for example if list of fields is **["cvid", "organization", "projectname"]**, it should return something like this in the following format

```
{'cvid' : 'value', 'organization' : 'Honda', Proj :[{'projectname' : 'asd'}, {'projectname' : 'asdsd'}]
```

Where should I write this function, so my code is more modular? I was thinking about writing it inside DataObj but I wouldn't know what are the attributes of object composed inside DataObj. How to achieve what I am trying to do in more object oriented way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between `__getattr__` and `operator.attrgetter`, you could make this work fairly easily:

```
class DataObj(object):

    def __init__(self, cvid, cvname, address, get_info):
        self.cvid = cvid
        self.cvname = cvname
        self.address = address
        self.prof = PROF("Honda", "Jason Jones")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Called when an attribute is accessed which is not found on DataObj
        # You can limit the loop to avoid checking some attributes, or
        # remove the loop if only self.prof should be checked
        for member in (self.cvid, self.cvname, self.address, self.prof):
            try:
                return getattr(member, name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise AttributeError(name)

        # If only self.prof should be checked, the function could simplify to:
        # return getattr(self.prof, name)
```

Then you can make a simple utility function that runs against a `DataObj` to get an arbitrary set of key value pairs from it:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def extractdata(dataobj, *names):
    return dict(zip(names, attrgetter(*names)(dataobj)))
```

Or as a member of `DataObj`, just name the first param `self` to match convention:

```
def extractdata(self, *names):
    return dict(zip(names, attrgetter(*names)(self)))
```

`__getattr__` allows delegation of attribute lookup to contained objects, and `attrgetter` allows you to retrieve a set of arbitrary attributes in a simple way.

Comment: Can you explain me this part attrgetter(*names)(self) ?

Comment: @paris_serviola: `attrgetter` make a function that retrieves the provided name(s) from whatever it is called on. So if `getname = attrgetter('name')`, then `getname(foo)` is equivalent to `foo.name`. With multiple names, it returns a `tuple`, so `getfoobar = attrgetter('foo', 'bar')` makes an object such that `getfoobar(x)` is equivalent to `(x.foo, x.bar)`. So with star unpacking, we take the names, and create a getter for all of them, then immediately apply the getter to the object. On further consideration, this won't work if `names` is only one name, so you'd need to special case that.

Answer (score 2):

All I did was simply add `__iter__` which basically says hey, you can iterate over me, if you cast the object to an iterabale container type.

```
class Proj(object):
    def __init__(self, projectname, projecttype):
        self.projectname = projectname
        self.projecttype = projecttype

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ("projectname", self.projectname)


class PROF(object):
    def __init__(self, organization, manager_name):
        self.organization = organization
        self.manager_name = manager_name
        self.project_list = [Proj("asd", "asd"), Proj("asdsd", "asdsd")]

    def __iter__(self):
        for proj in self.project_list:
            yield (dict(proj))


class DataObj(object):
    def __init__(self, cvid, cvname, address):
        self.cvid = cvid
        self.cvname = cvname
        self.address = address
        self.prof = PROF("Honda", "Jason Jones")

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ('cvid', self.cvid)
        yield ('organization', self.prof.organization)
        yield ("Proj", list(self.prof))


do = DataObj("1", "heinst", "A Street, Somewhere, USA")
print dict(do)
```